# Static variable access

Tags: c#

Generally we access the static variable with class name but when it is declared in non-static class we can access it in same class without class name.
Can anyone explain how it works?

```
class abc
{
   public static int x = 20;
}
class Program
{
    static int x = 10;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        abc.x = 30;
        x = 40;
        Console.WriteLine(x);
        Console.WriteLine(Program.x);
        Console.WriteLine(abc.x);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is only one `x` in the scope of `Program`. What is the problem?

Comment: _"... when it is declared in non-static class..."_ - it doesn't depend on whether this class is static or not

Comment: _"we can access it in same class without class name"_; if you use `using static` directive then you can access any static variable without class name.

Comment: That means if the static variable defined in specified scope like class program in this context then there is no need to access it with class name. It behaves like local variable. It is correct?

Comment: @ManojKadam - "It behaves like local variable" - No. The compiler behaves in a certain way, the variable does not.

Comment: What makes you think that you _shouldn't be able to_ access without class name?

Comment: Why do you think this special for static variables? This is just [qualifying a name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/using-namespaces#fully-qualified-names) in an unambiguous way. A static member is one per class, hence you need to qualify it like `[namespace].[class].[name]`. An instance member is one per instance, hence you need to qualify it down to the instance. If there are no name collisions, you can avoid fully qualifying a name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's no different from the usual behaviour of members. Let's look at an example with an instance field:

```
public class MyX
{
  public int MyValue;
}

public class MyY
{
  public int MyValue;

  public void SomeMethod()
  {
    MyValue = 42; // MyValue is in scope here, since it's a member of `MyY`,
                  // and we're in an instance method on `MyY`

    var myX = new MyX();
    myX.MyValue = 50; // MyValue must be qualified with an instance

    var myY = new MyY();
    myY.MyValue = 60; // MyValue must be qualified, otherwise `this` is implied

    var myself = this;
    Console.WriteLine(myself.MyValue); // Prints 42
  }
}
```

The only difference between the static and instance case is that there's only one `MyY.MyValue` if `MyValue` is static, so `MyY.MyValue` and `MyValue` are the same object. And to prevent a common programmer error, you cannot access static members through an instance reference (i.e. if `MyValue` is static, you cannot do `myY.MyValue` - you have to do either `MyValue` or `MyY.MyValue`).

For bonus points, C# added the `using static` declaration. This allows you to use static members without qualifying them. For example:

```
public class MyMaths
{
  using static System.Math;
  using static System.Console;

  public void DoSomeMath()
  {
    WriteLine(Sqrt(PI * 42));
  }
}
```

It should be noted that all of this is part of C#, the language. The compiler *always* qualifies everything; the intermediate language produced by the compiler doesn't do any guessing. The resulting code from `MyValue = 42` is exactly the same as from `this.MyValue = 42`:

```
ldarg.0                  // Load `this` (the first argument of an instance method)
ldc.i4.s    2A           // Load the constant 42
stfld       MyY.MyValue  // Store the value 42 to the field `MyY.MyValue` on instance `this`
```

Comment: Thanks for brief explanation